# An exception occurred: java.lang.Throwable: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [struts2]: could not be initialized

Tags: java

I am using liberty profile 8.5. Recently migrated from older struts to struts 2.5.3. The issue is when my_application started/restarted in Bluemix cloud, I see below error like javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [struts2]: could not be initialized. Please check below attached logs for more details and assist. thanks

```
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: [ERROR ] SRVE0315E: An exception occurred: java.lang.Throwable: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [struts2]: could not be initialized
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:157)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4982)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at [internal     classes]
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [struts2]: could not be initialized
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$1.create(ContainerImpl.java:71)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$1.create(ContainerImpl.java:75)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache.internalCreate(ReferenceCache.java:79)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.<init>(ContainerImpl.java:344)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$5.create(ContainerImpl.java:299)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache.internalCreate(ReferenceCache.java:79)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache$CallableCreate.call(ReferenceCache.java:155)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$7.call(ContainerImpl.java:516)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:514)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.LocatableFactory.create(LocatableFactory.java:32)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:129)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:52)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:560)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:466)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:499)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:63)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: ... 1 more
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache$CallableCreate.call(ReferenceCache.java:155)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectors(ContainerImpl.java:93)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:569)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$5.create(ContainerImpl.java:295)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:181)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:476)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:75)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$9.call(ContainerImpl.java:532)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:143)
Nov 08 13:32:58 my_application/[APP/PROC/WEB/0]: ... 1 more
```

Comment: please [*format*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47201357/edit) your question as it is completly unreadable

Comment: *Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager*

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the dependencies are not well resolved, while its deployed in bluemix. If you are using a maven project, and you have your dependencies resolved, you can just package the application with the server and deploy it to bluemix using cf commandline. Please refer the bluemix docs for the commands.